# Нужно удалить элемент списка

Tags: python-3.5

```
    def modify_list(n):
    s = ""
    for i in range(len(n)):
        if n[i] % 2 == 0:
            n[i] = n[i] // 2
        elif n[i] % 2 > 0:
            s += str(i)
    for j in s:
        b = int(j)
        del n[b]
    return n
les = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

print(modify_list(les))
```

ошибка : **func.py", line 10, in modify_list
    del n[b]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range**

Comment: Это происходит потому, что вы определили индексы нечетных элементов на полном списке, а пытаетесь удалить элементы по этим индексам уже в измененном. Лучше использовать `list.remove(obj)` в этом случае.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что после удаления элементов из начала списка изменяются индексы оставшихся элементов и уменьшается его длина, поэтому в итоге Вы пытаетесь обращаться к элементам за пределами списка. Правильным решением будет удаление не с начала, а с конца:

```
def modify_list(n):
    s = ""
    for i in range(len(n)):
        if n[i] % 2 == 0:
            n[i] = n[i] // 2
        elif n[i] % 2 > 0:
            s += str(i)
    for j in reversed(s):
        b = int(j)
        del n[b]
    return n

les = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(modify_list(les))
```

---

Если смотреть глубже, то хранить индексы в строке неправильно, и для этого лучше использовать список:

```
def modify_list(n):
    s = []
    for i in range(len(n)):
        if n[i] % 2 == 0:
            n[i] = n[i] // 2
        elif n[i] % 2 > 0:
            s.append(i)
    for j in reversed(s):
        del n[j]
    return n

les = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(modify_list(les))
```

---

Оптимизируем это ещё больше. Условие `n[i] % 2 > 0` будет выполняться всегда, поэтому его можно исключить. А далее воспользуемся генератором списков:

```
def modify_list(n):
    return [x // 2 for x in n if x % 2 == 0]

les = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(modify_list(les))
```

Следует учесть, что последний код не модифицирует исходный список, а создаёт новый.